# Accessing session from another routes

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication

Hi guys i try to implement really simple authentication with Express.js. Confused on why the session can't be read from another routes. Here my code:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var sess = req.session;
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" +username+ "' && password='" +password+"'";
  connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, field){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(rows[0]){
      console.log('Username: ', rows[0].username);

      var sessionObj = {
        username: username,
        role: rows[0].role,
        fullname: rows[0].nama_lengkap,
        email: rows[0].email
      };      
      sess.obj = sessionObj;
      res.render("../views/login/home", {person: sess.obj});
    }
    else{
      console.log('no data found');
    }

  });
```

i want to call it from get routes but it not works.

Comment: You can use session over a server but if you want to access session value on view then you have pass session values in a different way like we can not access session values directly so pass it like `let person = req.locals.person = sess.obj;  res.render('home",{person:person});  `and access it on view side

Comment: oh i got it @SantoshSuryawanshi thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the session variable use cookie as a result you will be able the access it in the front end and with by able to send it in the next request back to the server